# Add "Return to" to FOSUserBundle login form

Tags: twig, fosuserbundle, symfony

The title already says everything.
What code do I have to enter where?

If you dont understand the title, I mean to give a template something like this

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user'_security_login', {}|merge({'redir': 'blog_default_index'})) }}">Link</a>
```

and the output should be... (example)

```
<a href="http://localhost/login?redir=http://localhost/blog/index"
```

and i think the controller would need something like...

```
/*
 * @Route('/login', defaults={"redir" = "blog_default_index"})
 */
```

Please help. I actually have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to build the `href` in two steps:

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}?redir={{ path('blog_default_index') }}">Link</a>
```

Alternatively if you add a `_target_path` hidden input to the login form, the user will be redirect to that path:

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path('blog_default_index') }}" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually worked. i just entered the line in the form. Now i only have to find how to get the page where he came from.

Comment: It is possible to get the referer in a controller with $request->headers->get('referer'). In Twig you can get it in a similar way, with app.request.headers.get('referer').